# Apache Drill in Docker container: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: docker, parquet, apache-drill

I'm using Apache Drill to convert csv data to parquet.

I want to do this in a distributed manner, so I spin up a Docker container, run code similar the example below to convert to CSV.

When I run one instance at a time, this works well. But when I spin up several containers simultaneously, the operation often fails with this stack trace:

```
Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:72)...
```

I don't know much about Drill - I haven't used it for anything before this. 
I get the big idea that multiple instances of Drill cannot be running simultaneously, but these Docker containers shouldn't know about each other.

The one thing they have in common is that they write to a common (shared) output folder. But each file name is unique.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Are there configuration settings I should look at?

The code I'm running is similar to this:

```
alter session set `store.format`='parquet';
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.`/fp9gr34f/parquet_tmp_output` AS
SELECT
CASE when columns[0]='source_file' or columns[0]='' then CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) else CAST(columns[0] as VARCHAR(100)) end as `source_file`,
CASE when columns[1]='column1' or columns[1]='' then CAST(NULL AS INT) else CAST(columns[1] as INT) end as `msg_command`,
CASE when columns[2]='column2' or columns[2]='' then CAST(NULL AS INT) else CAST(columns[2] as INT) end as `msg_length`
FROM dfs.`/path/to/my/file.csv`
OFFSET 1
```

Comment: can you share your `docker run` command?

Comment: I'm actually using AWS Batch, which launches the container.

Comment: OK, then how about the AWS batch job definition?

Comment: It spins up the container, pulls a script from S3, and runs it. Nothing fancy. 
Everything works if I run one at a time. It seems that Drill must be doing something fancy with symbolic links and maybe the /tmp folder. 
It's not clear to me how two containers might share /tmp in AWS land...

Comment: This suggests that multiple instances of Drill are running on the same ec2 instance. This should not be a problem with docker unless you are telling docker to bind to the host port or you have --net=host configured as a flag when you launch the container. Please provide us the script that you are running in your job definition. If you cannot provide the whole script please provide the line that does `docker run` as was previously suggested. Without this info we cannot pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I think the core issue is that /tmp was mapping to the same volume across the containers on the same host.
I didn't spend much time trying to find a solution for this - I found that the org.apache.parquet libraries make it pretty simple to write some code to convert CSV to parquet without the overhead of including Drill.